# Doctrine2 and Symfony2 - Best practice to use types for a specific entity

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have this database structure:

- Comments
- DocTypes
- Papers
- Videos
- Discussions

The users can make comments on one those 3 doc types: paper, video and discussion.

For that, I created 3 types in my DocTypes

```
id    name
1     paper
2     video
3     discussion
```

In the Comments table, I have the doc_type_id.

Now, I would like to use the Comment entity and be able to make comments. What is the best practice in this case? Is there a way to do the relations between the Comment and the Paper entity for example, or should I do everything manually: check the type and make a switch case?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I mean, what would you want to reach?

Comment: I will need for example to insert a new comment and then on some other page display all paper comments. For that, I will need to create a relation between the entities, or do this manually by checking the type etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `DocType` is a mapped superclass and Paper, Video, Discussion extend it. In that case, you could just add `OneToMany` relation from `DocType` to `Comment`.

This should create a field `doctype_id` in your `comments` table referencing `doctype` table. This is assuming you're using class table inheritance.

You could then just do:

```
 $paper = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Papers\Class\Here')->find(5238953);
 $paper->getComments();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right, I am using the DocType class as mappedSuperclass and I have the doc_type_id in the Comments Class. Is it possible to get some more details about the connection between Papers and comments for example?

Comment: What kind of details?

Comment: I am trying to create the supperClass, but can't find examples. The question is: How will the $paper->getComments() know which comments to take from teh table comments.

Comment: I just checked some docs, it is not better to use the single table inheritance http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: It's your decision whether you'll use single table inheritance or not. Doctrine knows how to do `$paper->getComments()` automatically because it knows `$paper` id. When you run `getComments()` it will run some SQL similar to this: `SELECT ..... FROM Comments WHERE doctype_id = 5238953`.

Comment: Hm, you didn't got my point. The doctype_id (called doc_type_id in my example) is the id of the table DocTypes, where i have 1 for paper etc.

Comment: Also, in the comments table i can have multiple document_id that are the same but with different doc_type_id.